# Finding all integral curves to $x^2 \partial_x + y \partial_y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

> Find all integral curves to the vector field $v(x,y) = x^2\,
>  \partial_x + y\, \partial_y$. See which ones are defined for all $t
>  \in \mathbb{R}$

So, I have to find all curves $\gamma(t)$ that satisfy $v(\gamma(t))=\gamma'(t)$. Right? Let's assume that $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$. By plugging it in $v$, we get the equations

$$\frac{d\gamma_1}{dt}=\gamma_1^2 \implies \gamma_1=0 \,\,\,\text{ or }\,\,\,\, \frac{d\gamma_1}{\gamma_1^2}=dt\implies\gamma_1(t)=\frac{1}{C_1-t} \,\text{ or }\, \gamma_1(t)=0$$
$$\frac{d\gamma_2}{dt}=\gamma_2 \implies \gamma_2 = C_2e^t$$

So, it seems that all integral curves for $v$, in the absence of any information about the starting point, must be of the form $\gamma(t)=(\frac{1}{C-t},Ke^t)$ or $\gamma(t)=(0,Ke^t)$.

But what about $\gamma_{\star}=(\frac{1}{t},e^t)$? This also seems to be an integral curve but I can't see how it can be found by solving the differential equations.

Where is my mistake?

Edit: I just figured the answer and realized that I had made a stupid calculational mistake. $\gamma_{\star}=(\frac{1}{t},e^t)$ doesn't satisfy $\gamma_1^2 \partial_x + \gamma_2 \partial_y = \gamma_1' \partial_x + \gamma_2' \partial_y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $\gamma_1$ isn't correct.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\gamma_1}{\gamma_1^2}=\mathrm{d}t\implies\gamma_1(t)=\frac{1}{C-t}.
$$

Comment: OK. Thanks. I'll fix it. But how does this answer my question? How do you get $(\frac{1}{t},Ke^t)$ as an integral curve? That's an integral curve. Isn't it?

Comment: $(t^{-1},e^t)$ is not an integral curve.  At any point $(c^{-1},e^c)$, the integral curve through that point is $(1/(c-t),e^{c+t})$.

Comment: not sure what you mean.  The $C$ is there for the finite-time blowup (forward or backward in time).